# Using Macros Copy and Paste At Last Row

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, macro-recorder

I need to copy and paste rows data only in a spreadsheet using Google Macros.
But I tring to recording Macro to keep my functions work.
And it gives the result just paste a values to the next function(+1) .
So However, I wish that paste a new row data at bottom row before would create a new row.
And the way is
First create a new row at the bottom row
Second paste insert any row data that I selected.

```
function _3333() {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  spreadsheet.getActiveSheet().insertRowsAfter(spreadsheet.getActiveRange().getLastRow(), 1);
  spreadsheet.getActiveRange().offset(spreadsheet.getActiveRange().getNumRows(), 0, 1, spreadsheet.getActiveRange().getNumColumns()).activate();
  spreadsheet.getCurrentCell().activate();
  var sheet = spreadsheet.getActiveSheet();
  sheet.getRange(spreadsheet.getCurrentCell().getRow() - 1, 1, 1, sheet.getMaxColumns()).copyTo(spreadsheet.getActiveRange(), SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_NORMAL, false);
};
```

[image]

Comment: Although I'm not sure whether I could correctly understand your question, I proposed a modification point as an answer. Could you please confirm it? If I misunderstood your question and that was not useful, I apologize.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your situation, how about the following modification?

#### From:

```
sheet.getRange(spreadsheet.getCurrentCell().getRow() - 1, 1, 1, sheet.getMaxColumns()).copyTo(spreadsheet.getActiveRange(), SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_NORMAL, false);
```

#### To:

```
sheet.getRange(spreadsheet.getCurrentCell().getRow() - 1, 1, 1, sheet.getMaxColumns()).copyTo(sheet.getRange(sheet.getLastRow() + 1, 1), SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_NORMAL, false);
```

- In this modification, your `getCurrentCell()` is copied to the next row of the last row.
- If you want to copy `getCurrentCell()` to the last row, please modify it to as follows.

  ```
    sheet.getRange(spreadsheet.getCurrentCell().getRow() - 1, 1, 1, sheet.getMaxColumns()).copyTo(sheet.getRange(sheet.getLastRow(), 1), SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_NORMAL, false);
  ```

### Added:

From your following replying,

> I wish that paste a new row data at bottom row before would create a new row. And the way is First create a new row at the bottom row Second paste insert any row data that I selected.

1. Insert a new row to the bottom row.
2. Copy and paste the selected row to the inserted new row.
3. Those are the same active sheet.

In this case, how about the following sample script?

#### Sample script:

```js
function myFunction() {
  var sheet =  SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var lastRow = sheet.getLastRow();
  sheet.insertRowAfter(lastRow);
  var selectedRow = sheet.getRange(sheet.getActiveRange().getRow(), 1, 1, sheet.getLastColumn());
  selectedRow.copyTo(sheet.getRange(lastRow + 1, 1), SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_NORMAL, false);
}
```

Comment: I'm sorry for description error.
I wish that 
paste a new row data at bottom row before would create a new row.
And the way is
First create a new row at the bottom row
Second paste insert any row data that I selected.

Comment: @Edward Thank you for replying. I apologize for the inconvenience. From your question, I couldn't understand your replying. I deeply apologize for this. From your replying, I added a sample script. Could you please confirm it? If that was not useful, I apologize again.

Comment: WOW wonderful It's working. 
Oh my god ,you are a genius.

Comment: I appreciate that you’ve found some glitches in the system. But,I'm new here.I apologize that I need at least 15 reputation that I cast a vote. :<

Comment: @Yuri Khristich Thank you for your always support.